# ElasticSearch Filters Aggregation using DateRange Filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been using the Filters Aggregation in ElasticSearch which allows me to specify independent filters each providing separate counts for each filter provided.

I can't get a DataRangeQuery to run as a filter.  If I add a DateRangeQuery as a filter Elastic is giving me the following error.  Does anyone know of a way to get a Date Range Query as a filter into a Filters Aggregation?

"search_phase_execution_exception"

Below is a sample use case for what I'm trying to do from a business perspective.

Content type:  Tasks

**Due Date Facet**

- Due Today Minus 7 Days
- Due This Week
- Due Next Week

I've provided a code snippet below of the relevant NEST/.Net Elastic code.

```html
aggs.Add(facet.Name, new FiltersAggregation(Constants.CONST_FACETNAME_DUEDATE)
{
OtherBucket = false,
Filters = new NamedFiltersContainer
{
 { Constants.CONST_TODAYMINUS7, BuildTodayMinus7Days(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString(), "endDate") && filter },
 { Constants.CONST_TODAY, BuildTodayQuery()},
 { Constants.CONST_THISWEEK, BuildThisWeekQuery()},
 { Constants.CONST_NEXTWEEK, BuildNextWeekQuery()},
 { Constants.CONST_NEXT30DAYS, BuildNext30DaysQuery()},
 { Constants.CONST_LASWEEK, BuildLastWeekQuery()},
 { Constants.CONST_NO_DUE_DATE, BuildNoDueDateQuery()}
}
});
....
private DateRangeQuery BuildTodayMinus7Days(string date, string field)
{
  var qDateRange = new DateRangeQuery
  {
    Field = field,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = date,
  };
  return qDateRange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this wasn't working.  I ran the query in Kibana and got this error which was more helpful:

"reason": "failed to parse date field [11/09/2019 16:06:15] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]"

So it seems that the DateRangeQuery is allowed in the FiltersAggregation.  My problem was that the date I was passing in wasn't formatted correctly and the error was misleading.

I fixed by formatting the date that was passed into the DateRangeQuery as follows:

'BuildTodayMinus7Days(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString(***"yyyy-MM-dd"***), "endDate")'